# Magento get all sales/order fields

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to export sales/order list from magento to an external DB.
I use this:

```
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(20);
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection()
```

I used `print_r($orders->getData());`  to see all the fields that I need to export but in this list there aren't all the fields that magento show me in the admin panel. 
where/how  can I find them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with $order->getData(); use following also for more informations

Use $order->getBillingAddress() for billing address details

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getBillingAddress()->getData());
```

Use $order->getShippingAddress() for shipping address details

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData());
```

Use $order->getPayment() for Payment method details

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getData());
```

Use $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod() for Shippment method details

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()->getData());
```

Comment: thank you this is helpful, i'm wondering now if there's a fast way to get all the fields because in this way it shows a lot of data that i don't need to use